# IEs(7&8) render basic fonts slightly larger

Tags: fonts, rendering, font-size, internet-explorer-7

```
a {font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 9px;}
```

Apparently IEs render font-size: 9px slightly larger. 'slightly-large' enough to break a layout. Can somebody please please help me with this issue?? I am kinda annoyed now :(

Answer (score 2):

The layout will be slightly different depending on what browser you're using and what fonts are installed.  You can never count on 9px text being exactly a certain size.

Part of the challenge of web design is to build enough flexibility in your layout so that this doesn't become an issue.

Comment: so basically - it is what it is, correct? unfortunately I didn't design the layout :( so yea, I kinda need to make it work.. Thanks AWM, I really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the line-height. This will help uniform the font across different browsers.

```
a {font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 9px; line-height: 1.3em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a reset css. On google you can find lots of information about that.